# Erdas Imagine 2020 Currupt Sibling warning

Tags: image-processing, geospatial

I am consistently getting warnings/errors about Corrupt Sibling or Corrupt Child when recoding data or just saving layers that heave been recoded. What does this warning mean? How can I resolve these issues?